# How do I add fixed header/footer to pdf file when converting from html

Tags: html, css, pdf, puppeteer, html-to-pdf

I want to convert html to pdf. I was wondering if there is any way to add fixed header and footer to the pdf. I have been looking around the web, @page css is used to add it but its not working for me. Or am i using it wrong? Please help.

```js
window.print();
```

```css
 *,
        ::after,
        ::before {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        html {
            font-family:'sans-serif';
            line-height: 1.15;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 1.5;
            color: #000000;
            text-align: left;
            background-color: #fff;
        }

        .wrapper {
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        @page {
            size: A4;
            margin-top: 0.25in;
            margin-bottom: 0.25in;
            border: 1px solid black;
            @top-center {
            content: 'Hello World';
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Html</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra. Rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque. Purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor. Massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit. At auctor urna nunc id cursus metus aliquam. Diam quam nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi. Quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse. Nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus. Sem nulla pharetra diam sit. Viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat. Ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas. Vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi. Pharetra massa massa ultricies mi quis hendrerit dolor. Tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat duis.

</p>
      <p>Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis. Et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit pellentesque. Varius vel pharetra vel turpis. Velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus. Aliquam sem et tortor consequat id porta. Orci porta non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero. Elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo. Vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra. Aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt. Viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit amet. Phasellus vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim. Accumsan tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper. Vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus. Eget duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut.

</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. The thing is, that your operating system pdf converter does not fully support @page syntax. You can try to convert your code to PDF using [PrinceXML Converter](https://www.princexml.com/download/) and your headers and formatting is here.